Set windows shortcut to launch a command prompt and a command within it
I want to generate a Windows shortcut for launching Anaconda navigator, without the command line window open.
With PYTHONDIR=C:\Users\User1\Anaconda\, if the target is %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe (command C1), when launching the shortcut I get a message
# Please activate the conda root enviroment properly before running the
# `anaconda-navigator` command.
...

and Anaconda navigator does not launch.
If the target is %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\activate.bat root & %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe (command C2), when launching the shortcut I get a command window with log messages that keeps open and Anaconda navigator launches. The command window closes after closing the navigator, and pressing a key.
If the target is %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /S /C "%PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\activate.bat root & %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe" (command C3), I get the same behaviour.
If the target is %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /S /C "%PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\activate.bat root && start /D \".\" %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe" (command C4), I get a similar behaviour, except that when I exit the navigator the command window closes without requiring a key press (better).
If the target is a batch file that executes either of C2, C3 or C4, the result is the same.
Is there a way to achieve the same, but without keeping the command window open while the navigator is running?

I can't test this here.. but perhaps.. %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /S /C "call %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\activate.bat root && start %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe"

@SeñorCMasMas - No, it behaves the same as my C4.

in old days I faced same issue to execute my .bat file to reset my WiFi connection, to solve this I created a .vbs file and place my .bat file path in .vbs file and run .vbs as an Administrator rights.
for your knowledge below is my resetWiFi.vbs as an example for you.
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\Scripts\wwwconnectiontest.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing

and create Task to run on startup with TaskScheduler.

You state, "when launching the shortcut I get a command window with log messages that keeps open."
In the shortcut to the batch file, set Run: to Minimized.

For example I created a batch file to run Firefox as a single instance, SIFirefox.bat. A link o that file was created. After creating the link, Run: was changed to Minimized.
Of course, the CMD prompt is there, but minimized, unless you use START, which starts a task, and then allows CMD to terminate, while the task continues.
The script below uses START that way. Note that NirCmd is used to raise the Firefox window, if already running but minimized, i.e., to set focus on it.
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
exit

:running
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NirSoft\NirCmd\nircmd" win activate process firefox.exe 
exit 

[Also note, that after reinstalling as regular user, Firefox moved from Program Files to AppData.]
